# How to Change ASP.NET Label Text from C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This seems to be a simple question, but I just can't figure it out.

I have a DropDownList given value 1 to 4 to each of its options, I've also set OnSelectedIndexChanged to the DropDownList in order to trigger the text in a Label to change.

Now the issue is when the DropDownList option is changed, the Label text doesn't change. I have no idea which part of my code causes this issue, especially when the browser console returns no error.

Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:
The DropDownList

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <div class="form-inline">

            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_basic_layer_select" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" Style="width: auto;" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl_basic_layer_select_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                <asp:ListItem Value="1">ArcGIS</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="2">Web Tile</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="3">WMS</asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="4">WMTS</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>

        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

The Label

```
<div class="col-lg-9">
    <asp:Label ID="url_tips" class="color_red" runat="server" Text="initial text" />
</div>
```

C#

```
protected void ddl_basic_layer_select_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string type = ddl_basic_layer_select.SelectedItem.Value;

    if (type == "1")
    {
        url_tips.Text = "1111111111111";
    }
    if (type == "2")
    {
        url_tips.Text = "2222222222222";
    }
}
```

Comment: is your method `ddl_basic_layer_select_SelectedIndexChanged` triggered at all ?

Comment: You are missing the markup that triggers events inside an UpdatePanel

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Comment: @Pribina Yes it is. The console was returning an error from the method until I fixed it.

Comment: @Steve Should I use <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger>?

Comment: @JerryChen is it by design that label is outside of Update panel and is it requirement? can it be moved inside ?

Comment: @Steve There're elements between the DropDownList and the Label, so yes I think it must be outside of the UpdatePanel. Is there a walkaround without putting the Label inside the UpdatePanel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put label inside another UpdatePanel and set the UpdateMode to conditional. UpdatePanel causes selected parts of a page to "refresh". In order to trigger a change outside "selected" parts which is label in your case, need to create another UpdatePanel.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode=Conditional>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="url_tips" class="color_red" runat="server" Text="initial text" />
            </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```